# Cloudflare setup with S3 bucket on sub domain

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare, web-development-server

I have one sub-domain abc.xyz.com and I  want to setup clouldflare cdn for images coming from s3 bucket and want to replace the url of amazon s3 with cdn.abc.xyz.com so that clouldflare cdn will work.

How would I do?

Thanks in advance.

I tried doing it by adding cname but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is your domain abc.xyz.com registered with CloudFlare?  Is it possible to share the actual domain name so that we could check the DNS records returned by `dig`?

Comment: This is what I see:
`ANSWER SECTION:
goodhealthbyyourself.megawecare.com. 3600 IN CNAME goodhealthbyyourself.megawecare.com.cdn.cloudflare.net.
goodhealthbyyourself.megawecare.com.cdn.cloudflare.net. 300 IN A 104.21.83.210
goodhealthbyyourself.megawecare.com.cdn.cloudflare.net. 300 IN A 172.67.181.243`
Do you know what are these IPs the CDN forwards to?

Answer (score 1):

To replace the S3 url with your subdomain, you would have to set up a CloudFront distribution with an [alternate domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) and then point the CloudFlare's CNAME record to the CloudFront distribution's URL.

Comment: In this case, however, CloudFront will act as a CDN too.  Not sure with two CDNs caching behavior will interact.

Comment: I setup an AWS S3 bucket for an e-commerce production site a while back. I had to setup Cloudfront as well to use a custom domain with S3, afterwards I put Cloudflare in front of the S3 bucket. If you need to invalidate the cache for an object on S3 you can use a Cloudfront query string which is configurable from what I remember. And then on Cloudflare you can use the API to also clear the cache when needed. You can also do it manually via the Cloudflare UI. This approach worked OK for our use case, this way we saved a lot of money related to S3 and Cloudfront costs.